# Data Toggle not working with Navbar Fixed Top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using a Bootstrap 3 navbar static top with nav pills. And that it works.
I cannot make data toggles working when the navbar is fixed to top.

This is the snippet with the navbar static top:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page_1" data-toggle="pill">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page_2" data-toggle="pill" >Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="page_1">
          Page 1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page_2">
          Page 2
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here it does not work:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_1" data-toggle="pill">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_2" data-toggle="pill" >Page 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="page_1">
              Page 1
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page_2">
              Page 2
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data toggle is working, it's just that your content is overlaid by the `navbar`. Take a look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top):

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other
>   content, unless you add `padding` to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your
>   own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is
>   50px high.
>
> `body { padding-top: 70px; }`
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

Example here: http://www.bootply.com/pGzO62Dp9L

Answer (score 0):

When the navbar is fixed, the next div starts at the same spot. So the pills are working, but the navbar is covering the content. You need to add padding to the top of your container.